# How to correctly use a model mapper with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Dear stackoverflow users,

I am working on a large project containing lots of models, repositories, entities etc...

The project is following the MVVM pattern and therefore also using some DTOs + mappers.
I decided not to use Automapper and instead create the mappers manually.
Now, there is one part of DTO mapping that seems to be very confusing to me and that is how to actually use it properly.

Below is some example code of what the architecture looks like.
To be able to actually use the mapper inside of a LINQ expression, I first have to call .ToEnumerable() followed by .ToList().
To me, this seems like a very bad idea as it would consume more memory for each query?

(The code below has been modified from my actual code, to get rid of irrelevant code)

Example code: (In the getter is where I think I am doing it wrong)

```
public class TestClass
{

        private readonly IGenericRepository<TestDbConext, int, Test> _testRepository;
        private readonly TestMapper _testMapper;

        public List<Test> TestList
         {
           get
            {
              return _testRepository.Entities.ToEnumerable().Selext(x =>  _testMapper.MapFromDataModel(x)).ToList();
             }
         }
}
```

TestMapper.cs

```
public class TestMapper : IModelMapper<TestDto, Test>
    {
        public TestDto MapFromDataModel(Test dataModel)
        {
            return MapFromDataModel(dataModel, new TestDto());
        }

        public TestDto MapFromDataModel(Test dataModel, TestDto viewModel)
        {
            viewModel.Id = dataModel.Id;
            viewModel.Description = dataModel.Description;
            return viewModel;
        }

        public Test MapFromViewModel(TestDto viewModel)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Test MapFromViewModel(TestDto viewModel, Test dataModel)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

IGenericRepository.cs

```
public interface IGenericRepository<TContext, in TKey, TEntity>
        where TEntity : class
    {

        IQueryable<TEntity> Entities { get; }

        TEntity SingleOrDefault(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate);

        TEntity FirstOrDefault(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate);

        IQueryable<TEntity> Where(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate);

    }
```

GenericRepository.cs

```
public class GenericRepository<TContext, TKey, TEntity> : IGenericRepository<TContext, TKey, TEntity>
        where TContext : DbContext
        where TEntity : class, IEntity<TKey>
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork<TContext> _uow;
        private readonly DbSet<TEntity> _entities;

        public IQueryable<TEntity> Entities => _entities;

        public GenericRepository(IUnitOfWork<TContext> uow)
        {
            _uow = uow;
            _entities = _uow.Context.Set<TEntity>();
        }

        public IQueryable<TEntity> Where(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return _entities.Where(predicate);
        }

        public TEntity SingleOrDefault(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return _entities.SingleOrDefault(predicate);
        }

        public TEntity FirstOrDefault(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return _entities.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
        }

    }
```

Comment: The [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh212132%28v=vs.103%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) say that `ToEnumerable` returns an enumerator from the observable sequence. It is not like you store the collection once again in memory because of it. Personally, I think the code is fine.

Comment: Thank you Andrey.
I must of been mistaken! Reason why I am so careful about memory usage is because the userbase is quite large and I need to make sure it the software does not eat do much. I wil leave the question open for possible suggestions :)

Comment: Why did you leave AutoMapper. Please see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do any other thing. If you need to convert an entity recovered from a database, and map it to a DTO class, you need to materialize the original entity to map it to your DTO instance.

However you made a bad choice when you left AutoMapper. AutoMapper has a very interesting extension to use with EF, which is [Queryable Extensions](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions). With your mapper you have to recover full entities from the database, i.e. get the values from all the columns, to map only the ones you need. This extension takes care to only bring the needed columns. I recommend you using AutoMapper unless you have a very strong reason not to do so.

Comment: Thank you Jota, it all makes sense now!
For a big project like this I am not using it for maintainability reasons.
While I think Automapper is absolutely beautiful, it has the risk of silent errors.
Especially since the database the the software is talking to will change quite a bit over the years, refactoring together with Automapper might be a pain in the a** :P

This article explains it quite well: http://www.uglybugger.org/software/post/friends_dont_let_friends_use_automapper

Regarding recovering full enteties, that is something I will have to look into! Thanks!